# Refiners in SP 2013 for Managed metadata fields, shows the unique GUID!

Tags: 2013, search, refiner

The question is very simple
Documents on this site have managed metadata fields, and I have selected the refiners for this on the search refiner webpart on the search results page.

However I see the ID after the text value.
How can I prevent that? not very user friendly

http://screencast.com/t/LKh3zWQh

Comment: How is your Managed Property set up? Seems like you have mapped it to the wrong Crawled Property, or chosen the incorrect Managed Property from the Refiners list

Comment: Yes that is probably the reason, as I didnt to which crawled properties to map it, then I had to map it to multiple to be sure the search would work.  Can you please explain how should I map a managed property to field of type: manged metadata?

Comment: If it is managed metadata field, correctly provisioned, SharePoint should create a Managed Property automatically. Look for a managed property named ows_YourColumnName or similar

Comment: so, the tax one is the wrong one

Comment: Yep, for refiners at last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the managed property called

```
ows_YourFieldName
```

not

```
ows_taxidYourFieldName
```

The taxid one will include the GUID, unwanted for Refiners. This is my experience at least.

Found another post stating the same here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/99f06b1a-59ca-43ab-bc13-d5d8deb7841f/managed-metadata-search-refiners-show-as-guids?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: I am confused with the refiners and the search.  Lets say I have a managed metadata field called Industry. I want to use it both in search like this (Industry:Food) or also in refiners.  If I map it to ows_Industry is that enough, or I have 2 create 2 different properties one for the search and another for the refiner?

Comment: This is really a different question, but shortly: if you mean free text search it should be OK to use either one of them. If you do need results based on for example a Managed navigation term, you should use the ows_taxid one (to be sure to get the distinct hit based on the GUID of the term)